# Xcode Parse Issue Expected ']'

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

I don know Why i keep receiving this error Parse Issue Expected ']' , any help would be appreciated.

```
  locationManager didUpdateToLocation FromLocation
        - (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager
    didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation
    fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation {
        NSLog(@"%@", newLocation);
        self.speedView.text = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", (speedCount)
  I Receive the error on this line    [newLocation speed]];

        }
```

Comment: Could you format your question a bit better. It's hard to read

Comment: The error message says it all. Looks like you've got one too many ]'s. Count them and see if they match up.

Comment: Yep that was the problem, thanks for the help guys

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a typo in code..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's take a look at your code:

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager
        didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation
        fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation 
{
    NSLog(@"%@", newLocation);
    self.speedView.text = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", (speedCount)
   [newLocation speed]];
}
```

Well, as you can see, the line staring with `self.speedView.text` does not end with a semicolon and it also does not have a square bracket to terminate the `stringWithFormat` call AND it has an extra square bracket.

You probably meant to do this:

```
self.speedView.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d %f", speedCount, [newLocation speed]]; //Show both speedCount and speed in your text view(?)
```

OR:

```
self.speedView.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", [newLocation speed]]; //Show only speed
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I got it to run without the error.

Comment: No problem!  Out of curiosity, which one were you intending to do?  Also don't forget to accept answers that helped you/gave you the solution to your problem!

Comment: The first one self.speedView.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d %f", speedCount, [newLocation speed]]; and no problem.